# Side by side child divs in parent div

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 2.3 I've created two `.gold-ratio .span6` parent divs and each one contains a `.left-ratio` and `.right-ratio` div.  Inside my `.left-ratio` div is an image and inside the `.right-ratio` div is some text describing the image.  However, my `.left-ratio` div fills the into parent div and the text from the `.right-ratio` div is no where to be found.  Everything is set to `float: left` and both the child divs are `display: inline-block`.  Not really sure why the image is taking up everything.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ugSR9/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="row center">
           <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="span6" id="item1">
                    <div class="gold-ratio">
                        <div class="ratio-left" id="pic1">
                            <img src="img/arch/studio4_1.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratio-right">
                            <h3>Some Info</h3>
                            <p>Detailed Info</p>
                        </div><!--/.ratio-right-->
                    </div><!--/.gold-ratio-->
                </li><!--/.span6-->

                <li class="gold-ratio span6" id="item2">
                    <div class="ratio-left" id="pic2">
                        <img src="img/arch/studio4_1.jpg"/>
                    </div><!--/.ratio-left-->
                    <div class="ratio-right">
                        <h3>Some Info</h3>
                        <p>Detailed Info</p>
                    </div><!--/.ratio-right-->
                </li><!--/.gold-ratio .span6-->
           </ul><!--/.thumbnails-->
    </div><!--/.row .center-->
```

CSS:

```
.gold-ratio {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
}

.left-ratio {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.right-ratio {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT: The Images I'm using are larger than the div so I have the left div cut off all overflow.**

UPDATED [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ugSR9/1/)

I can't post photos because of my low reputation, but maybe this will help:

What I have:

```
___________________
|                 |
|                 |
|_________________|
```

Here is what I want:

```
___________________
|             |   |
|             |   |
|_____________|___|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in linking your markup with your CSS rules. In your HTML I can see `<div class="ratio-left">` and `<div class="ratio-right">`, but in your stylesheet you are trying to style `.left-ratio` and `.right-ratio`.

As you can see [**here**](http://jsbin.com/esusoh/1), fixing this rule fix the issue and makes them behave as, I believe, you are expecting.

### Update

To solve your problem you have to better understand how **floating** works. I will try to explain it concisely and simply sticking to the matter at hand, not getting into the details of one of the most convoluted aspects of CSS:

When an element is floated, it is pushed as far as possible in the direction specified by the float property **of the containing element**. Contrary to the *absolute positioned elements*, **floated elements remain part of the flow of the document**. This, in a nutshell, means that they occupy their space.

In your case, this is the problem.

You have a container with a fixed width (`li.span6`). Inside this element you have another container (`div.golden-ratio`) containing two containers (`div.left-ratio` and `div.right-ratio`). These last two containers are designed to `float:left` (you can get rid of `display: inline`, because a floated element is automatically made into a box; perhaps you were looking at `display:inline-block` which would save you from a lot of headaches).

However, since these last two containers **have no fixed width**, they take whatever width of their content.

`div.left-ratio` takes the width of the `img` inside it; which is not constrained but by `max-width: 100%`. This refers to 100% of `div.span6` since it is the last element with a fixed width.

**By taking the whole space `div.left-ratio` pushes `div.right-ratio` in the next row**. When you say that it is nowhere to be found, it is because your `div.golden-ratio` have the `overflow:hidden` property set, and a fixed height. `overflow: hidden` means: **hide everything that goes beyond my fixed width/height**; hence, the pushed element is *disappearing*.

To achieve what you want to do, **you have to make space for `div.righ-ratio`** by giving `div.left-ratio` (or its content) some width constraint (whether it's pixels, percentage or whatever you wish). In [this updated example](http://jsbin.com/esusoh/5) I show you how you could do it.

…well… so much for *being concise*…

Comment: Then, can you explain what exactly do you expect to happen? Could you post a screenshot/mockup of what you want?

Comment: I can't post images due to my low reputation, but I tried to draw something for you, the section on the left holds the image, and the section on the right holds the text.

Comment: Updated my answer to further explain the matter at hand. Tell me if there is something you still don't understand.